# Add Text To TXT File

Tags: file, batch-file

I Don't Know How To Add Text To A .txt file.
When I Do This

```
@echo off
echo te > file.txt
echo xt >> file.txt
```

The Text File Show's This:

```
te
xt
```

I Know That echo text >> filename.txt adds a line but I don't know how to make the batch file add text like this:

```
text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a trick with the `SET /P` command.

```
@echo off
<nul set /p .=te>file.txt
<nul set /p .=xt>>file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can put it in one line**

```
echo text >> file.txt
```